# run Python functions from vb.net

Tags: python, vb.net, vb6, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I am new with vb.net. I am trying to call python functions from vb.net but getting  error that 'Invoke' is not a member of 'Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ObjectOperations'

```
Imports Microsoft.Scripting
Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Hosting
Sub Main
 Dim engine As ScriptEngine
        Dim scope As ScriptScope
        Dim i As Integer


        engine = Python.CreateEngine()
        scope = engine.ExecuteFile("C:\Working.py")
 Dim v = engine.Operations.Invoke(scope.GetVariable(methodName))
```

' name of the method thaT NEEDS TO INVOKED AND GET THE RETURN VALUE.
 Can anyone please  recommend me better way to make this work? I have already seen this link :http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/08/14/calling-ironpython-functions-from-net.aspx

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is a link to a blog about using the dynamic keyword to execute Python methods, https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/dynamic-language-integration-in-a-c-world/ Also, VB6 has nothing to do with VB.NET, you might want to edit your tags.

Comment: Thanks for the link! But  i was looking for answer in vb.net language. Cannot create the Python engine and scope objects in vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
  Sub Main(ByVal args() As String) 
    Dim pyRT As ScriptRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime() 
    Dim workingObj As Object = pyRT.UseFile("working.py")   
    workingObj.methodName() 
  End Sub
```